# UIWebview does not load it's Content when app is reviewed by App Store team

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am submitting an app which includes UIWebview. UIWebview loads inside collection view and show charts data. It is working fine in debugging as well as in distribution mode (when installed via diawi). But when apple review team review it, content does not load.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your backend which you used to display the data in webview, I faced a similar issue when I integrated the Firebase framework into my project and for me, it was logging in perfectly but when we send it for approval for the apple team it shows some error during login. it was solved by contacting the firebase team, this was caused by their firewall protection.

PS:- I suggest you use WKWebview instead of UIWebview(deprecated). And talk to your backend team if the content you are showing in webview owned by your organization

Comment: Yes, it is owned my our organization.

Comment: then ask them to help you there may be something like mine issue